# How to get a callback working with SimpleModal

Tags: jquery, simplemodal

I've been unable to catch the onclose from within simplemodal.  please give me a hand if you can as i'm new to jQuery...

```
<a href="http://url/" onclick="$(this).modal({width:833, height:453}).open(); return false;">
```

works, but i would like to call a javascript function whenever the modal dialog is closed.  How do i attach, say updateTable(); onto the close event??

I've tried

`<a href="" onclick="$(this).modal({onClose: alert(1);$.modal.close();}).open();"`

and all stupd variations of this, but honestly looking at the nested functions in the example page only made me dizzy (the second example also has the href, but it doesnt let me post it here)....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to

- Click on a link (e.g. with id clicker)
- The page defined by the URL in the href of this `<a href="...">` tag should be the modals content
- When the user closes the modal you want to trigger some action and close the modal

HTML:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" id="clicker">Click me!</a>
```

JavaScript

```
var c = function closer() {
    $.modal.close();
    alert("Done!"); 
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#clicker").click(function() {
        $.modal(
            '<iframe src="'+this.href+'" width="833" height="453">asd</iframe>',
            {onClose:c}
        );
        return false;
    });
});
```

Check http://jsbin.com/ofimi for a working sample

Answer (score 0):

First you do not have to add the onclick attribute when using jQuery.
Assume

```
 <a id="clicker" href="http://url/" >Click</a>
```

Then

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#clicker").click(function(){
          $(this).modal({width:833, height:453, onClose: function(){ 
             //your code here}})
          .open(); 
          return false;
      });

 });
```

The $(this) reference actually refers to the a tag, maybe you might want to use a div called dialog like this:

```
 <div id="dialog"></div>
```

and change the jQuery to

```
$("#dialog").modal(...)
```

---

UPDATE: Based on your comment. try this.

```
   <head>
      <!-- Include your script tags here to load the jQuery and simplemodal scripts -->
      <script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function(){
              $("#clicker").click(function(){
                 $("#dialog").modal({onClose: function(){ 
                  alert("Closing");
                 }
                 });
                return false;
              });
          });


      </script>

      </head>
      <body>
           <div id="dialog"></div>
           <a href="#" id="clicker">Click</a>
      </body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help... not using onClick will definitely make the code neater, but unfortunately it is not running my code when i close the modal... i tried a simple

alert('hello');

and it doesnt work...

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but why would I want a div?  I'm loading content which is external, inside the modal, it is getting whatever is on the clicker href, and loading it as an iframe.  All I need to do is to know when the user closes the dialog box so i can refresh stuff on the page.

Comment: The $(this) in your original code refers to the a tag which is a link. Its as if you are making the link into the modal dialog, which I doubt is what you want. You want to use another container such as a div for that. Otherwise you can use any other container you like.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but the code above still doesnt work...  Firstly it wont open even the modal, so I added the .open() to it, at which point it opens the modal, but doesnt open the URL inside the href, instead it is trying to open 'undefined', and finally, when I press the X it doesnt alert as it should.... did this code actually work for you? i'm trying on 2 browsers....

Comment: Vincent, just to answer your comment, i *DO* want the link as my modal, as it causes the modal window to contain the contents of the link (iframe like)... this is precisely what I want... This part was already working in my original code, but what i want now is capturing the close so i can deal with it.

Comment: Try adding onClose: function(){ 
                  alert("Closing");
                 } to {width:833, height:453} like this: {width:833, height:453, onClose:function(){ 
                  alert("Closing");
                 }}